# How to remove RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK from excel sheet?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I scraped data from a website that contains a half-million records to an Excel file. My problem is one column stores Arabic characters, and I can't apply any formatting to these cells while they contain a RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK. I don't **know** it is a RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK, but I copied the character from the cell (I can't see it) and converted it to ASCII, and got `(226 128 143)`. I searched for this code and I found "RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK".

I tried to find a way to search the Excel sheet by ASCII code, but I couldn't find anything.

I'm using Excel version 15.27 on Mac El Capitan.

How can I remove this character from the whole column?

Comment: What do you mean "RIGHT TO LEFT MARK"? I assume you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)? Can you show some sample data, and a sample of the expected output?

Comment: Do you just want to remove a specific character? If so, just copy it, open the "find and replace" menu. Paste it in find, and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove characters from a column you can insert a 'helper column' and use that column for the text without the offending characters, which in your case is the right-to-left mark.  How you would do this depends on where the character is in the text and this is where it can also get a little different with your situation.

If the offending character is a comma for example and it is at the far right of the text you need to use `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)` and if it is on the far left of the text you would need to use `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1))`.

In your case you are removing a non-text character so you need to use an ASCII code in a `CHAR()` reference or unicode number in a `UNICHAR()` reference. The right-to-left mark is under unicode 8207 so substitute the `","` in the required formula above with `UNICHAR(8207)` making the required formula either `=LEFT(A1,FIND(UNICHAR(8207),A1)-1)` or `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(UNICHAR(8207),A1))`